# pandas groubpy().size() PSQL equivalent

Tags: python, sql, pandas, psql

In `pandas`, I can do something like this:

```
>> df
     col_a    col_b
0        a       x7
1        a       x7 
2        a       x9
3        b       ab
4        b       ab
```

```
>> df.groupby(['col_a', 'col_b']).size().reset_index()
     col_a    col_b     0
0        a       x7     2
1        a       x9     1
2        b       ab     2
```

So, there is a new column counting the quantity of groups ('col_a', 'col_b')

I am learning SQL, and it's been hard to me to do the same in PSQL. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you would use `group by` and `count()`:

```
select col_a, col_b, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by col_a, col_b
```

Comment: Wow! That's true! Thank you!